Makefile return linker error when you try to compile after changing any file and works properly just running it a second time
I created this Makefile:
`
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

-include $(DEPFILES)

#### END CONFIG ####

all: $(TARGET)
    
# LINK AND EXECUTABLE
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $? $(SANITIZERS) $(LIBS)
    # Create a backup
    cp $(TARGET) $(TARGET)_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
    @echo "Finished executing the target '$@' for project '$(APPNAME)'"

# COMPILE
${OBJDIR}/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) 
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) $(SANITIZERS) -c $< -o $@  
    @echo "Built '$<' for project '$(APPNAME)'"


Not showing all file just what i think important lines, the rest are the declaration of mostly directory variables and the phony targets.
If the project is clean and i do make : No errors
if after that i change 1 file and recompile :
mkdir -p obj/classes/ 
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g3 -iquoteinc -iquoteinc/classes -iquoteinc/wxwidgets/ -iquoteinc/wxwidgets/panels -MMD -O0 -I/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/include/wx-3.2 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK3__ -D__WXGTK__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -pthread  -c src/classes/blockcard.cpp -o obj/classes/blockcard.o  
Built 'src/classes/blockcard.cpp' for project 'trellosim'
mkdir -p bin
g++ -o bin/trellosim obj/classes/blockcard.o  -pthread -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu-3.2 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14.1.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: en la función `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [Makefile:82: bin/trellosim] Error 1

And finally, without do anything else, do make a third time and no errors at all :
mkdir -p bin
g++ -o bin/trellosim obj/wxwidgets/panels/menupanel.o obj/wxwidgets/panels/rightpanel.o obj/wxwidgets/panels/propertiespanel.o obj/wxwidgets/panels/boardpanel.o obj/wxwidgets/panels/wxblockcardpanel.o obj/wxwidgets/mainwindow.o obj/classes/project.o obj/classes/board.o obj/classes/blockcard.o obj/classes/card.o obj/main.o  -pthread -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu-3.2 
# Create a backup
cp bin/trellosim bin/trellosim_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
Finished executing the target 'bin/trellosim' for project 'trellosim'

Am I doing something wrong? Could this cause failings on the app or I can trust the last compilation will work. It does now but not sure if the project grow could become a problem.

Is that your complete Makefile? I don't see where you define TARGET.

$? expands as "the names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target, with spaces between them". Replace $? with $^ in your $(TARGET) recipe.
